# Solving mod congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

So i have a problem like this

```
34x ≡ 77 (mod 89)
```

This is how i try to solve it but it doesn't seem to work :( If anyone can give me a hint on how to proceed from what i have down below would mean a lot thanks.

I first use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to find the  inverse down below
[image: Extended Euclidean algorithm]

Since the gcd = 1 i look at the the fact that

```
37*77-(-32)*89=1
```

Therefore going from there since we live under `mod 89` we can cancel out `(-32)*89` so i continue with multiplying the inverse to my original equation.

```
37*34x ≡ 37*77 (mod 89)
```

Shouldn't it come out to be: `x ≡ 2849 (mod 89)` and let that be the answer? I know i am going wrong somewhere all help is appreciated.

Also sorry for formatting if it is bad quite new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got it backwards.  Given your equation, you have

$$37(77)\equiv1\pmod{89}$$

In other words, you have that $37$ is the inverse of $77$.  What you want is the inverse of $34$.  Multiplying both sides by that will yield $x$ on the left hand side.

Comment: I don't quite understand... So would i need to do is plug in the numbers 34, 89 into that sheet and it says `-34   13` Since the `-34` is with the `34` i multiply them and get `-1,156` and that mod `89 = 1`?

Comment: @user2166592 That second term in your sum is a multiple of $89$.  Therefore, if you take both sides $\pmod{89}$, that term drops out completely.  And yes, $-1156=-13\times89+1$, so $-1156x\equiv1x\pmod{89}$